# Optimizing Pymongo read queries

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have created a huge mongodb database. Following are its stats:

```
> db.stats() <br/>
{
        "db" : "test-sample-db",
        "collections" : 3,
        "objects" : 30700242,
        "avgObjSize" : 607.1807849592847,
        "dataSize" : 18640597036,
        "storageSize" : 19531558816,
        "numExtents" : 31,
        "indexes" : 2,
        "indexSize" : 2692111520,
        "fileSize" : 25691160576,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 5
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

I am using pymongo on Windows 7 (64 bit) (8 GB RAM) python 2.7 to query this database. Note that index is created on a field called "key". Query is simple, I just want all the documents having specified keys. I used $in for that as follows:

```
result = testdb.find({"key": {"$in":lt}})
for doc in result:
    pass
```

Size of "lt" above is apprx 1000. Hence this query will at amx return 1000 documents. What I noticed was that this query is quite slow. It takes about 5-6 seconds to perform this query and iterate over the cursor as shown in the above code.
Is there any way I can optimize this to make this operation much faster ?

Sample document:

```
{"key" : "abcd12xx", "data" : {"w1" : 1, "w3": 1, "w4" : 3}}
```

Output for query.explain() (Not that this for just 10 keys for saving space here. Normally I will have 1000 keys and hence this will be larger):

```
{    u'nYields': 0, 
     u'nscannedAllPlans': 19, 
     u'allPlans': [{u'cursor': u'BtreeCursor feature_1 multi', 
                    u'indexBounds': {u'feature': [[u'1000', u'1000'], [u'1001', u'1001'],
                              [u'1002', u'1002'], [u'1003', u'1003'], [u'1004', u'1004'],
                              [u'1005', u'1005'], [u'1006', u'1006'], [u'1007', u'1007'],
                              [u'1008', u'1008'], [u'1009', u'1009']]
                    }, 
                    u'nscannedObjects': 10, 
                    u'nscanned': 19, 
                    u'n': 10}], 
     u'millis': 0, 
     u'nChunkSkips': 0, 
     u'server': u'server:27017', 
     u'n': 10, 
     u'cursor': u'BtreeCursor feature_1 multi'
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe post a sample document?

Comment: Just added one sample doc

Comment: Could add explain output for this query?

Comment: I'd be curious to see how long this query takes if you just did 1000 single calls to test.find({"key":key}), especially if you built an index over "key"

Comment: also try running your testdb.find({"key": {"$in":lt}}).explain() in the shell and post the output here

Comment: Its apprx the same time if I use test.find_one()

Comment: Just added the output for explain() as well.

Comment: I am not a Windows user so it is wild guess but I would check if antivirus / firewall  doesn't interfere with communication between db and pymongo.

Comment: So basically, millis is 0 on 10 keys - so if you run this 1000 query more than once, does it get much faster? chances are it's just paging the data in the first time (or you may not have enough available RAM to fit the entire index into RAM in which case that could cause very bad performance too).

Comment: are you actually saying that find_one takes the same amount of time? 5-6 seconds?  explain() shows 0 millis.